# DiskAid is not recognising my IPOD

Tags: itunes, ipod

I installed DiskAid and its not recognising my iPod Shuffle (it's showing message "Please connect your device" when I have already plugged in my iPod). Is there any other good app for OSX which is useful to copy and paste music on iPod?

Comment: What prevents you from using iTunes?

Comment: I want to copy music from mac to ipod and vice versa

Comment: That's what iTunes does as well (and much better than DiskAid or any other similar tool), so is there a special reason to *not* use iTunes?

Comment: I tried to copy from itunes, but it does not allow even I tries to drag items from itnubes to mac

Answer (score 3):

To use DiskAid with an iPod Shuffle you need to enable "disk use" within iTunes.

- Plug your iPod shuffle into your PC or Mac.
- Open iTunes.
- Select your shuffle in the list on the left-hand side of the iTunes window.
- Check the "Enable disk use" box under Options near the bottom of the Summary tab within iTunes.
- Click Apply.

If you open DiskAid now, you should be able to use it with your shuffle.

Comment: Thanks Alistair, The "enable disk use" checkbox is already selected. Please check screen shot here.

Comment: http://snag.gy/ucuQH.jpg

Comment: Might be an idea to turn off "Manually manage music" and try again.